Autohomeomorphisms of Stone-Cech remainder
I really want to read into autohomoeomorphisms of the stone cech remainder of  $\mathbb{N}$. Does anyone have some references/papers that really go into detail on this topic? Preferably one/s that cover/s most of the preliminaries as well.
Thanks in advance.

Probably the best to start with to get a deeper insight into $\beta \mathbb N$ is van Mills's article in the Handbook of set theoretic topology (1984), if you can access it.
This paper from 2014 seems to be a survey about what you are looking for.
This paper from 2022 about problems on $\beta \mathbb N$ contains a chapter about autohomeomorphisms, and certainly a huge list of references also to this subject.

Exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot.
